# How does PHP generate an HTML file?

Tags: php, html, mysql

OK, I'm sticking my neck out here. I'm starting out with PHP/mySQL and this is my second question ever.

HISTORY
I set up a single table in the customer database and made a PHP inquiry form to INSERT a new row every time the form is submitted. That's fine.

Now I want to retrieve that data based on some search criteria. The search function will come later; for now, I'm hardcoding the search criterion, e.g. "WHERE cusNum = 101".

I found this somewhere recently:

```
<?php
$table = $dom->createElement('table');
$domAttribute = $dom->createAttribute('id');
$domAttribute->value = 'my_table';

$tr = $dom->createElement('tr');
$table->appendChild($tr);

$td = $dom->createElement('td', 'Label');
$tr->appendChild($td);

$td = $dom->createElement('td', 'Value');
$tr->appendChild($td);

$table->appendChild($domAttribute);
$dom->appendChild($table);
```

but I don't understand how to use it. Up to this point, I can display the whole table using:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <?php
    [$conn = new PDO(blahblahblah), connect_error, $query->execute, etc. ...]

    //Display results
$result = "";
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$result .= "<tr>
                    <td>" . $row['firstName'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['lastName'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['state'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['zipCode'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['phone1'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>
        </tr><br><br>";
}

//Close connection by making it blank
$conn = null;
?>

<table id="results" style="vertical-align:top">
    <thead>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>ZIP</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php echo $result; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I think I'm missing something basic about the program's flow. How do the pages relate to each other? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

For the first piece of code, you are simply creating a table. Try and visualize it. You have your DOM and under it you create a table. You create an 'id' attribute for it and assign it a value.

You then create the children rows (tr) for the table and for each row you are creating the children data elements(td).

For the second piece of code, you are doing almost the same using html elements/tags. You create the table and for the table header you use `<thead>   </thead>`. Under the table body, you are displaying the table row using `<tr>`.

P.S. Don't use 
 after closing the table row. A new `<tr>` will create a row in the next line. Adding `<br>` will add space after the table ends. If you need extra spacing use css attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know what this code does by itself, but I need to understand how it fits into the whole process. Right now, I just want to learn how to add to a customer database and query from it using proper, modern code (like using PDO instead of MySQL extension). Can someone outline the basic files needed to do this? (I've seen it called CRUD). I have an html inquiry form and a PHP that does the INSERT.